# When do the Bleach Movies occur in relation to the anime?

Tags: bleach

I'm wondering at what point in the anime series of Bleach do each of the movies occur? This way, when I watch the series I can stop at a specific point to watch the appropriate movie.

Comment: Rikken is almost rite part from the second movie ikkaku already know how to use bankai just doesn't show until first contact so that is the one I have to dispute on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the main story, the movies are never mentioned because they are like fillers and not canon to the main story. But it's possible to verify when they occur by some facts, by some situations that we saw in the movie:

- The first movie, *Memories of Nobody*: Ichigo is able to use his bankai in the World of the Living, so it happens after the Bount Invasion arc and before the Arrancar one as he's still unable to use his hollow form. So, it is between **episode 109 & 110**.
- The second movie, *The DiamondDust Rebellion*: Ikkaku use his bankai, so maybe it happens after the first invasion of Arrancars (the one defeated by Toshiro team) and before they entering in Hueco Mundo. In episodes, **something near 138**.
- The third movie, *Fade to Black*: I think it happens nearly to *The DiamondDust Rebellion* during the Arrancar's fight, but before they entering in Hueco Mundo because Ichigo still uses the first form of his hollow mask:

  [image: Ichigo wearing his hollow mask]
- The fourth movie, *Hell Verse*: In this movie, Ichigo uses the second form of his mask and transforms into his full hollow form, so he already fought Ulquiorra in Hueco Mundo and returned. Repeating, it's like a filler, **after episode 299**.

Comment: "fought Ulquiorra in Hueco Mundo and returned", does he do this before battle with Aizen?

Comment: Yes, they start fight in Hueco mundo at chapter 266 to 272. Then, at chapter 286, Ichigo manage to return to protect Karakura and fight Aizen.

Comment: after youve finished episode 197 then you watch the 3rd movie...*^*

Comment: How is Ichigo able to fight in the fourth movie if his powers disappeared after the aizen fight, and this was before the fullbringer arc based on his shihakusho. It just doesn't fit into the timeline anywhere. But it was a great movie.

Comment: @user8428 It's not supposed to fit. And Kubo has washed his hands of the hell movie, so there's even less reason to expect any cohesion.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this suggested edit (already rejected) to see if it is worth editing in: http://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14155