# Where do the Bleach filler arcs and movies fit in the anime timeline?

Tags: bleach

I know they are not canon but I would like to know between what episodes/arcs these can be watched so they do not interrupt the canon and flow better chronologically. Like placing them in a way where they do not outright interrupt and break the chronology like I heard all but the Bount arcs does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which episodes of Bleach are filler?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/which-episodes-of-bleach-are-filler)

Comment: for movies we have this question [When do the Bleach Movies occur in relation to the anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/when-do-the-bleach-movies-occur-in-relation-to-the-anime)